# Getting Settings and Arguments with SBTs InputTask

Tags: scala, sbt

I've written an [SBT plugin](http://yobriefca.se/sbt-tasks/) that allows SBT users to define arbitrary tasks in their project that can be run (with full classpath and dependencies loaded) from SBT itself.

The body of the functionality looks like this

```
  def installTask(taskName: String, taskDescription: String = "") = {
    TaskKey[Unit](taskName, taskDescription) <<= (dependencyClasspath in Runtime)
      .map(loadTask(_, "tasks", taskName.capitalize))
      .map(_.run)
  }


  private def loadTask(dependencies: Keys.Classpath, taskPackage:String, className: String) = {
    val dependenciesUrls = dependencies.map(_.data.toURI.toURL).toArray
    val classLoader = new URLClassLoader(dependenciesUrls, null)
    val taskClass = s"$taskPackage.$className"
    classLoader.loadClass(taskClass).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Runnable]
  }
```

So people can, in their SBT file do this

```
import SbtTasks._

installTask("seedDB")
```

And when the call `sbt seedDB` the `tasks.SeedDB` will be executed in the application context.

Now the problem - I need to do this but accept arguments.  I've got as far as understanding how to accept arguments

```
  def installTaskWithArgs(taskName: String, taskDescription: String = "") = {
    val input = InputKey[Unit](taskName, taskDescription)

    input := {
      val args: Seq[String] = Def.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
      println(args)
    }
  }
```

But I can't work out how to, in this context access the values of my `dependencyClasspath` within the InputTask

```
  val dc = (dependencyClasspath in Runtime)
```

I also tried Commands but they seemed a bit more troublesome and all content appears to promote InputTasks over Commands anyway.

So - how do I accept arguments in a task while also getting access to the `dependencyClasspath`?

NB: Code has been elided for brevity please excuse any obvious exclusions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few more days of experimenting I finally found a workable solution,

```
def installTaskWithArgs(taskName: String, taskDescription: String = "") = {
    val input = InputKey[Unit](taskName, taskDescription)

    input := {
      val args: Seq[String] = Def.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
      val dc = (dependencyClasspath in Runtime).result.value.toEither.right.get
      println(args)
      println(dc)
    }
 }
```

I want to specifically call out the line

```
val dc = (dependencyClasspath in Runtime).result.value.toEither.right.get
```

While this isn't the most stable line (it assumes the happy path) this is at least a good starting point (and for my needs currently works)

Answer (score 1):

I think `inputTaskDyn` is your friend here:

```
input :=
  Def.inputTaskDyn {
    val args = Def.spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
    val dc = (dependencyClasspath in Runtime).value
    ...
  }.evaluated
```

for some background and links to further reading, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/999